# Definition of quasi-geodesics

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

I was going through the books *Géométrie et théorie des groupes* by Michel Coornaert, Thomas Delzant, Athanase Papadopoulos and *Metric Spaces of Non-Positive Curvature* by Martin R. Bridson, André Haefliger. These books give different definitions of quasi-geodesics. In the former,

> Let$\ X$ be a metric space and$\ f: [a,b] \to X$ a continuous path, with$\ - \infty \leq a \leq b \leq \infty.$ We say that$\ f$ is a$\ (\lambda,k)$-quasi-geodesic (where$\ \lambda \geq 1$ and$\ k \geq 0$) if for every sub-interval$\ [a',b']$ of$\ [a,b],$ we have:
> \begin{equation}
>     l(f([a',b'])) \leq \lambda |f(a') - f(b')| + k.
> \end{equation}
> We say that$\ f$ is a global quasi-geodesic, or simply a quasi-geodesic, if there exists a couple$\ (\lambda,k)$ such that$\ f$ is a$\ (\lambda,k)$-quasi-geodesic.
> We finally say that$\ f$ is a$\ (\lambda,k,L)$-local-quasi-geodesic(where$\ \lambda$ and$\ k$ are as above, and$\ L>0$) if for every sub-interval$\ [a',b']$ of$\ [a,b]$ such that$\ l(f([a',b'])) \leq L,$ we have:
> \begin{equation}
>     l(f([a',b'])) \leq \lambda |f(a') - f(b')| + k.
> \end{equation}

I am also attaching the image of the definition below,
[from the book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBnDs.jpg) while in the latter, the definition is,

> A$\ (\lambda, \epsilon)$-quasi-geodesic in a metric space$\ X$ is a$\ (\lambda,\epsilon)$-quasi-isometric embedding$\ c : I \to X$, where$\ I$ is an interval of the real line (bounded or unbounded) or else the intersection of$\ \mathbb{Z}$ with such an interval. More explicitly,
> \begin{equation*}
>     \frac{1}{\lambda} d(t,t') - \epsilon \leq d(c(t),c(t')) \leq \lambda d(t,t') + \epsilon
>     \end{equation*}
> for all$\ t, t' \in I$. If$\ I = [a, b]$ then$\ c(a)$ and$\ c(b)$ are called the endpoints of$\ c$.

Are these definitions equivalent? If so could you please show it?

Comment: Are you sure you copied the 1st def correctly? Without a lower bound, the constant path would be a quasi-geodesic, which isn’t right.  In any case, the second def is clearly different from the first since in it quasigeodesics need not be continuous, or even defined everywhere on the interval.

Comment: @AndyPutman I have attached the image of the definition from the book. I think I have translated it correctly. Anyways, the 1st definition only has an upper bound.

Comment: You did translate it correctly.  As I said before, these definitions are not equivalent.  Neither implies the other.  Bridson-Haefliger’s definition is the standard one.

Comment: Ohk...Thank you!!